# Simulate MQTT TLS login by MQTT.FX in linux?

Tags: linux, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am having some problems using mosquitto client in linux, more specifically I need to use mosquitto_sub but I don't really get how I should authenticate.

All I have is a json config file for MQTT.Fx, that works fine when imported in that application. I can see there are username and password, as well as host information, and that SSL/TSL is enabled.

My question is: how can I do the same thing that MQTT.Fx does automatically since option *CA signed server certificate* is selected? I have been trying a lot of alternatives, like downloading server certificate and passing it as --cafile, generating new certificate, signing them, editing mosquitto.conf, but I didn't match the right combination of operations.

Any suggestion, please?

Edit: here is current command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h myhost.example -p 8883 -i example1 -u myusername -P mypassword -t XXXXXXXXXXXX/# --cafile /etc/mosquitto/trycert.crt
```

where file trycert.crt contains the response to following request (of course only part between BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE)

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername myhost.example -connect myhost.example:8883 </dev/null
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72186288/edit) the question to show the full actual `mosquitto_sub` command, details of what certs/keys you have and the error message that is generated.

Answer (score 1):

All the times I had problems with MQTT over SSL its been that the server cert chain of trust broken on my client.  In other words, the server i am connecting to has a cert.  This cert is authorized by another cert and so forth. Each of the certs in the chain need to be on the client.

If any of these certs are missing, the chain of trust is broken and the stack will abort the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get the problem, so I should add all these certs to one folder and pass it via parameter --capath?

Comment: Use this command to look at a server cert.  Here is one for google: openssl s_client -showcerts mqtt.googleapis.com:8883

Then do the same thing for the certs in /etc/ssl/certs and ensure they match that chain.

FWIW, I did a summary presentation on SSL as part of GDG Southern Devfest 2021 SSL for beginners.  Google it and it might help.